# Postman: SOAP Request with Attachment

Tags: soap, postman, attachment

How do you add an attachment to a SOAP request in Postman?

I have the following settings and have my SOAP xml in the 'raw' text box.

[image]

(I can do this in SoapUI, but would like to use Postman.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your pdf file to base64, then use that base64 code in your method.